# Cannot install dependencies for Elixir app

Tags: elixir

I have the start of an Elixir app, and trying to install any dependencies with

```
mix deps.get
```

results in

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

my mix.exs file:

```
defmodule Servy.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :servy,
      version: "0.1.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.3",
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      deps: deps()
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [
       extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
  end

  defp deps do
     [{:poison, "~> 1.3"}]
  end
end
```

I've looked around and found that it may be related to a memory error, but haven't found anything corresponding to Elixir that may be able to point me in a direction to investigate further.

```
OS: OSX 10.13.2
Processor: 2.5 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
```

If anyone needs any further system information just say, and I'll post it.

I can compile and run the app fine if I remove the dependencies.

Comment: Would you please try in upgrade Elixir / Erlang to at least 1.5.1 / 20.1 and re-check if the problems persist?

Comment: That fixed it thanks. Had to uninstall and re-install home-brew first in order to upgrade Elixir and Erlang. If you add your comment as an answer I'll mark it correct.

Comment: I am not sure it makes any sense to add an answer; something was broken in your environment, re-installation fixed it, everybody’s happy. If I were to put an answer, I’d write “don’t use MacOS for developement” in all caps :)

Comment: @mudasobwa i use macOS for development quite happily ;)  [I also have no problems upgrading elixir and erlang](http://drops.ryanwinchester.ca/3J1M1W1r3w1i), when needed.

Comment: @mudasobwa just answer it so it stops showing up in my list of unanswered questions 

Comment: Just vote to close the question and it will never be shown anywhere. Or feel free to answer it yourself.

Comment: @mudasobwa you should answer it so new-comers can easily spot the solution (and remove it from unanswered tab as well)

Comment: @FelipeSkinner no, I should not. This question should be closed as “the problem cannot be reproduced.” When developers use operating systems supporting the developement process out of the box, these issues never arise.